# Continuous error messages despite positive results when checked with minimal working example!

Tags: errors, miktex, compiling, biber

I get following error messages, I ran several checks, but just can't figure out where they're comming from! I use MikTex 2.9 and Biber 1.7. These are the error messages:

```
Line255: File ended while scanning use of \field. <inserted text> \par \begin{document}
Line92: Illegal parameter number in definition of \NewCount. <to be read again>1 \begin{enumerate}
Line92: Undefined control sequence.<argument> \blx@bbl@data \begin{enumeLine256: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 92. <inserted text>\fi \include{PSA4_Deckblaetter}
Line256: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 92. <inserted text>\fi \include{PSA4_Deckblaetter}
Line259: Undefined control sequence. \ps@plain -> \let save@@mkboth\@mkboth\ps@save@plain\let\@mkboth....
Line1: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 259 <inserted text>\fi <> PSA4_Globalisation_Meta.tex The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
```

When I run Biber I get this message:

```
Entity: line 1961: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document <bcf:section number="0"> ^
```

I compile frequently so I know exactly that everything worked fine until I wrote a new paragraph and included 8 new references. I use a meta `.tex` file and then include each chapter separately as an own `.tex`.

What I did so far:

- Checked my `.bib` file for wrong symbols or the like. Found some "&" and took them out and deleted everything else that was suspicous.
- I ran a mininmal example using my meta file code and then ran a check on each chapter separately including ALL the references.
- Ran another test only with the new paragraph I worte and only the new references.
- I checked all `.tex` files for any overlooked `\iffalse`. (I had used it before to check something, but deleted it then (completely!)) and checked for lonely `\begin{enumerate}`.

Everything works perfectly there! But if I run my original complete document I get these errors!

I know you guys want minimal examples, but all my code, references and text works perfectly within a minimal example. So I don't know what else I need to provide you apart from the full file.

Comment: Without seeing some code, it will be difficult for people here to diagnose your problem. That may require some effort on your part, but you need to isolate the problem first, and then post some minimal code that reproduces the error(s).

Comment: Hm. Ok. I'll try. I was hoping that someone could at least point me into a direction of where to look.

Comment: *No! Try not. Do. Or do not. There is no try.*

Comment: Sorry, but I've been doing that for the past 5 hours. If I'd know how, I would have already done it. No need to get unfriendly about it.

Comment: t was a reference to the `Empire Strikes Back`. I wasn't being unfriendly `:)`. How long is your file? Just remove anything that doesn't seem necessary and post it in your edited answer (if it's of reasonable size). Then people will be able to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Oh right. That's Yoda. Didn't catch that. :-) Sorry, guess I'm a little oversensitive, because this error is driving me crazy. I'll do that. Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non reproducible problem

Comment: @egreg Yes, it's about an non reproducible problem. But the OP's solution is generic - worth leaving up on this site.

Comment: If I had found an info like that on the web, it would have saved me a day writing on my thesis instead of wasting it on unnecessary error search. It might help others, too. But you guys are the experts on this. Do as you deem necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I was not able to create a minimial working example to reproduce the error. Obviously there is nothing wrong with the `.tex` files themselves. I deleted the "production" files in the folder, but MikTex was not able to recreate them and ran into a major error. 
I could not fix any of the errors, but **I found another solution** during my attempt (thx jubobs for making me try harder):

I moved everything to a backup folder. Copied only the `.tex` files back into my original folder. Renamed them. And boom! It's working perfectly! The renaming seemed to have an impact (although it does not make much sense to me).

Note: The old files in the backup folder still produce this error although they are the exact same `.tex` files. Guess some error must have caught iself up in one of the production files.

Comment: Same problem, the answer helped me.  However, I just deleted the aux files, rebuilt and it worked.  So I did NOT need to rename any files.  Renaming files should have the same effect as deleting the aux files.  My env. was TexStudio Windows 2.10.8,